# How to test the content in a Japanese language website?

Tags: manual-testing

We are migrating the existing japanese website and relaunching in our company platform. I need to do the content testing in the migrated site. Please help me how to verify the Japanese content with the legacy site.

Comment: If you're migrating existing content and it's been tested and verified before, then you probably won't have to test it again. Otherwise, as @MichaelDurrant suggests, you'll need to weigh up your options and decide what makes sense for the business.

Comment: My first question, what do you mean by migration to company platform? Is this static site and static content did not change? What do you mean by site content?

Answer (score 1):

For a one time move it may make the most sense to do this manually.

Put together a list of current functionality and content and verifies that it exists in the new system.

You'll need someone who knows Japanese.  That's not really avoidable until you are willing to take on considerable risk.  Websites that are translated by people who don't understand the language have a high risk of being wrong.

If you don't have / don't have access to, a translator either get one (think the internet) or state that the business needs to provide one or provide for the cost of one.  Throwing some figures out: if the cost is $1000, what is the expected *Revenue* from the japanese site over the coming year?  $300? Don't bother.  $300,000? you better bother.

Comment: Thanks Michael. We don't have resource who knows Japanese langauage. Is there any tool which can be used for comparing the legacy site content with the migrated site content?

Comment: No.  Every site is different and if you use any sort of automated translation it will likely be poor quality.  I would go back to management and state 'if we don't have a native speaker review the content we are at a high risk of error'.  A Japanese translator might be able to review the site in an hour or two (depending on size of site though), You just have to *decide to make the effort to get one* ('you' means the business in this case, not personally you).

Comment: btw I'm talking about a translator because although the requirement here isn't to translate from English to Japanese, it _is_ to make sure that the Japanese makes sense and is the same aws the intent of the original English.  Plus you have to be able to talk to the translator and you don't speak Japanese...